# Add comma in number after every thousand on event of "Enter" in a text box using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

This is a question from Angular JS.
I need to add "comma" after every thousand on event of enter in a text box.
Like, if enter a number 1000000 in a text box and hit"Enter" button, text box should now show the value 1,000,000

I am trying to do it using a directive.Please tell me how can I do it.

Comment: I suppose it should be something like this.                                           
              if (event.which == 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {                                          });          But don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Please help us help you by posting some code you have tried. A codepen that actually has the text box shown would really help.

Comment: Questions asking for **homework help** must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: How can we achieve the same thing OnBlur event instead of OnEnter event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a weird request to do it on Enter event, but you can try using a directive to listen for an event and change it to a comma separated number with a simple built-in `$filter` for numbers (or even currency). Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', [])
app.controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };
});

function Ctrl($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.OnEnter = function() {
    $scope.MyText = $filter('number')($scope.MyText);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-enter="OnEnter()" ng-model="MyText" />
    <br> {{MyText}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that example doesn't solve the problem of typing letters or any other characters other than numbers, you would need a pattern/parser within a directive.